# Angular Dynamic Components - Add Class and other attributes

Tags: css, angular, dynamic, attributes

I am using the following code for creating the dynamic components

```
import {
  Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, ViewChildren,
  ReflectiveInjector, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewEncapsulation, QueryList, Input, AfterViewInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';
import { IComponent } from 'app/app.icomponent';


@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  selector: 'dynamic-component',
  entryComponents: [HomeComponent, HighlevelSignalComponent],
  template: `
    <div #dynamicDiv [ngClass]="classFromMenu" >
     <ng-template #dynamicComponentContainer></ng-template>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [
    './dynamic-content.component.css'
  ],
})

export class DynamicComponent implements IComponent, OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  classFromMenu: any;
 @ViewChild('dynamicComponentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicComponentContainer: ViewContainerRef;


  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private route: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, ) {

  }

  .......

  buildComponent(passedData) {
   // orderAndObjs has the data for creating the component

      this.orderAndObjs.forEach(obj => {
        var componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(obj.component);
        var compRef = this.dynamicComponentContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);


     // compRef is the component that is created.
//Assuming the component that i am trying to create is <dynamic-component>. 


  //I want to add either a class or any other attribute like this
//<dynamic-component class="flex">
      });

    }
  }

}
```

The dynamic-component is created perfectly fine and everything is working as expected. But the only issue is I want to add a class for dynamic-component so that it can be

```
<dynamic-component class="dynamicClass">
```

Any help is appreciated :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hmm.. I usually add it to the `selector` of component that is supposed to be an entryComponent ...

```
selector: 'dynamic-component.someclass',
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to add attribute use attribute selector:

```
selector: 'dynamic-component[myattr=value]',
```

I call it **hidden feature of entryComponents**

but its declarative approach and can't be changed at runtime(indeed we can change it)

Comment: Good one. Didn't know that.

Comment: @yurzui .. Can you explain how it can be changed in runtime or while creating components dynamically.

Comment: While creating component dynamically you can get `ComponentRef` that has `location` property. `const compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory);
    compRef.location.nativeElement` Now you have access to element and can use whatever you want to change class or attribute. In angular we usually use `Renderer` See answer from estus

Comment: @Shrikey It should be defined on the component that is supposed to be dynamic if you want it to have some class like `flex` all the time. If this isn't your intention, this option won't work for you.

Comment: @yurzui,estus .. Thanks for your answers. I used selector attribute and also Renderer to achieve what i need. :)

Comment: of no use in angular 5.

Comment: @yurzui What if the the dynamic component is from 3rd party library like a component from Angular Material where we don't have an option of adding to selector ?

Answer (score 9):

In Angular 5/6, using Renderer2 from @angular/core, you can do something like below:

```
constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private route: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private renderer2: Renderer2) {

  }

buildComponent(passedData) {
  this.orderAndObjs.forEach(obj => {
    var componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(obj.component);
    var compRef = this.dynamicComponentContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);
    this.renderer2.addClass(compRef.location.nativeElement, 'flex');
  });
}
```

Comment: Agreed. In Angular 13 you can bypass the resolver and create your component with createComponent only. You can also add the class directly on the nativeElement without using Renderer2 wrapper, for example : compRef.location.nativeElement.className = 'flex';

Answer (score 7):

High-level DOM operations are performed with `Renderer2` provider. Considering that it was injected, it is:

```
this.renderer2.addClass(compRef.location.nativeElement, 'dynamicClass');
```

It should be noticed that depending on how dynamic element is attached to DOM, this may be unnecessary complication.

Considering that `dynamicComponentContainer` is real DOM element and not `<ng-template>`, the view of dynamic component can be directly mounted to the container, thus eliminating `<dynamic-component>` wrapper element:

Given the container:

```
<div class="dynamicClass" #dynamicComponentContainer></div>
```

It will be:

```
var compRef = componentFactory.create(
  this.injector,
  [],
  this.dynamicComponentContainer.element.nativeElement
);
```